# Set variable as query name in assigning table datasource

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with the syntax to pass the query name and set a table's datasource from an existing list of queries within the workbook.

```
Sub Button15_Click()

Dim qName As WorkbookQuery
Dim nSht As Worksheet

qName = Sheets("MainForm").Range("J3").Value
 WkBookName = qName
 nSht = Sheets("InvoiceForm").Select
Debug.Print WkBookName
LoadToWorksheetOnly qName, nSht

end sub

Sub LoadToWorksheetOnly(query As WorkbookQuery, currentSheet As Worksheet)
' The usual VBA code to create ListObject with a Query Table
' The interface is not new, but looks how simple is the conneciton string of Power Query:
' "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & query.Name

With currentSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
    "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=" & query.Name _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$18")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdDefault
    .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [" & query.Name & "]")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

End Sub
```

Does not like the qName variable syntax.  Error Msg _ object Variable or with block variable not set. on the setting of the qName.

Comment: How are the queries stored in the Workbook?  What library are you referencing for  your `Queries` object?

Comment: I am using Data Model/Power Query(Excel 2016 version)  I found code to create the queries on the fly, however, since I have the queries I was hoping to just reset the table on the invoice form to the required query.  see website:https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/VBA-to-automate-Power-956a52d1/view/Discussions

Comment: still looking for assistance with this